# How to force a XmlSerializer to serialize elements as attributes of a compiled type?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, runtime

I've given some predefined XML similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Points>
      <Point X="1.345" Y="7.45" />
      <Point X="1.123" Y="5.564" />
      <Point X="3.34" Y="2.5345" />
   </Points>
   <!-- and a bunch of other attributes and structures which are perfectly serialized and deserialized by the XmlSerializer -->
</Root>
```

And my goal is to deserialize it into a `List<System.Windows.Point>` using a `XmlSerializer` instance and vice versa. Therefore I've defined type like the following:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class RootClass
{
   public List<System.Windows.Point> Points { get; set; }
   /* and more properties */
}
```

My problem is that the `XmlSerializer` interprets the framework properties as `XmlElement`. In order to that they are only read and written as such, but not as attributes as required.

One solution I thought about, was defining a custom point type, which defines the `XmlAttribtueAttribute` for each coordinate property. And this custom point gets mapped to the `System.Windows.Point` structure. This looked like the following:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<Point> Points { get; set; }

[XmlArray("Points")]
[XmlArrayItem("Point")]
public List<CustomSerializedPoint> CustomSerializedPoints
{
    get { return this.Points.ToCustomSerializedPointList(); }
    set { this.Points = value.ToPointList(); }
}
```

But for this solution i've noticed, that the setter is never called, and the `XmlSerializer` calls the getter of `CustomSerializedPoints` about five times. It expects that there is a backing list, which has the same reference each call and which is never null. In order to that requirements, this is no solution for me, because I would need to keep the `List<CustomSerializedPoints>` in memory just for writing the points using attributes instead of elements.

So has someone a more practiable solution?

Additionally my `XmlSerializer` code:

```
/* ... */
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootClass));
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("file.xml");
(RootClass)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
/* ... */
```

Comment: See "[XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)", then tell us if you have more questions after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the way a class is being serialized/deserialized by altering its serialization attributes at runtime. [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) class provides such possibility. The following example code correctly deseralizes the XML you've provided:

```
XmlAttributes xa = new XmlAttributes();
XmlAttributes ya = new XmlAttributes();

xa.XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("X");
ya.XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("Y");

XmlAttributeOverrides xao = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
xao.Add(typeof(System.Windows.Point), "X", xa);
xao.Add(typeof(System.Windows.Point), "Y", ya);

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootClass), xao);
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("file.xml");

var result = (RootClass)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
```

Comment: Meanwhile I got something similar, but you were faster. Thank you, this solves the problem.