# Way to specify to always deserialize XML as [XmlAttribute]?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am using a class library and Web API from a 3rd party.  Some of their APIs return JSON and some XML.  They only provide a JSON class library, but "supposedly" the objects returned are the same.  I was thinking of trying to leverage the JSON library to deserialize XML as well.

I've examined the XML, and the XML returned from the web API has the members encoded as attributes except for arrays. If I was writing my own class library, I would just decorate the property with [XmlAttribute] and be done with it.  However, this is a third party library and I am trying to leverage the work they've already done.

Is there any way to specify before doing the deserialization for the XmlSerializer to act as if the data members are encoded as attributes?

Comment: Can I ask what you gain by having them as attributes? In my experience, I've run into large amounts of data being in attributes causing problems while using XML serializers in .NET, but I've never had issues with that same data being an XMLElement.

Comment: As an alternative, you might try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496334/c-sharp-to-convert-xml-attributes-to-elements

Comment: You could use `XmlAttributeOverrides` along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439057/how-to-force-a-xmlserializer-to-serialize-elements-as-attributes-of-a-compiled-t/19439381#19439381.  If you do, [**you must cache the assemblies in a Hashtable**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is not shown in the linked example.  For more on caching see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544517/xmlrootattribute-placement-when-deserializing-to-list/15545231#15545231

Comment: @MarkW I don't have a choice.  That is the way the Web API returns the data and they are not going to change it for me.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson Sorry... Your question makes is sound like arrays are not stored as XML attributes and you want them to be.